# Obter o mesmo resultado de uma query com join

Tags: mysql, select, join, sql-select

Já pesquisei em alguns fóruns, consultei meus livros e procurei em outras fontes, porém não encontrei algo que solucione meu problema.

Possuo uma query que consulta o valor em aberto em uma determinada tabela:

```
select negociacao_parcela.data_pagamento,
sum(IF(negociacao_parcela.pagamento_status_id = 1, negociacao_parcela.valor, 
0)) Aberto from negociacao_parcela
where negociacao_parcela.data_pagamento = '2018-01-22 00:00:00';
```

a qual me retorna o valor "R$ 125.482,26" (no momento da publicação desta).

Porém, preciso listar dados de outra tabela, de modo que se eu fizer quaisquer dos joins abaixo, o resultado é "R$ 191.702,28" (no momento da publicação desta).

JOIN:

```
select negociacao_parcela.data_pagamento,
sum(IF(negociacao_parcela.pagamento_status_id = 1, negociacao_parcela.valor, 0)) Aberto from negociacao_parcela
join negociacao_parcela_item on negociacao_parcela_item.parcela_id = negociacao_parcela.id
where negociacao_parcela.data_pagamento = '2018-01-22 00:00:00';
```

LEFT JOIN:

```
select negociacao_parcela.data_pagamento,
sum(IF(negociacao_parcela.pagamento_status_id = 1, negociacao_parcela.valor, 0)) Aberto from negociacao_parcela
left join negociacao_parcela_item on negociacao_parcela_item.parcela_id = negociacao_parcela.id
where negociacao_parcela.data_pagamento = '2018-01-22 00:00:00';
```

RIGHT JOIN:

```
select negociacao_parcela.data_pagamento,
sum(IF(negociacao_parcela.pagamento_status_id = 1, negociacao_parcela.valor, 0)) Aberto from negociacao_parcela
right join negociacao_parcela_item on negociacao_parcela_item.parcela_id = negociacao_parcela.id
where negociacao_parcela.data_pagamento = '2018-01-22 00:00:00';
```

INNER JOIN:

```
select negociacao_parcela.data_pagamento,
sum(IF(negociacao_parcela.pagamento_status_id = 1, negociacao_parcela.valor, 0)) Aberto from negociacao_parcela
inner join negociacao_parcela_item on negociacao_parcela_item.parcela_id = negociacao_parcela.id
where negociacao_parcela.data_pagamento = '2018-01-22 00:00:00';
```

Obs.: Todas as datas de pagamento possuem o horário '00:00:00'.

Estrutura das tabelas:

```
desc negociacao_parcela;
    id
    negociacao_id
    rps_id
    pagamento_status_id
    parcela
    valor
    data_pagamento

desc negociacao_parcela_item;
    id
    parcela_id
    negociacao_cobranca_id
    cobranca_id
    documento
    data_vencimento
    valor_aberto
    valor_montante
    total
    diasAtraso
    subtotal
    comissao
    jurosCredor
    jurosComissao
    jurosFinal
    protesto
    parcela
```

Grato desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso, se entendi corretamente seu objetivo, uma maneira é fazendo um SELECT tendo a tabela de itens como a principal e única fonte de dados do SELECT. O valor em aberto, busque com um SUB-SELECT. Vai perder performance, mas num SQL único, é o jeito.

Você ainda pode tentar aplicar um GROUP BY.

Comment: Andrey, obrigado por seu comentário. Infelizmente já havia tentado também.

Answer (score 0):

Conforme resposta do Andrey, o SUB SELECT retorna os mesmos dados que o SELECT atual. Desta forma, continua alterando os valores do resultado, uma vez que preciso buscar os dados da tabela 'negociacao_parcela', e juntar à 'negociacao_parcela_item'.

Somente na presença do join, onde quer que esteja, que os valores são alterados.
O mesmo serve para o GROUP BY, o qual substituí pelo WHERE e listei todas as datas.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia.
Nao tenho certeza se entendi bem. Se vc faz o select sem join, retorna R$ 125.482,26. Se vc faz o select com join, retorna outro valor, mas deveria retornar R$ 125.482,26. É isso?

Se sim, acho q a solucao seria query derivada.

```
select negociacao_parcela.Aberto, negociacao_parcela.data_pagamento, negociacao_parcela_item.qualquer_campo
from negociacao_parcela_item
    ,(
       select negociacao_parcela.data_pagamento,
              sum(IF(negociacao_parcela.pagamento_status_id = 1, negociacao_parcela.valor, 0)) Aberto, 
              negociacao_parcela.id_agrupador id_agrupador 
       where negociacao_parcela.data_pagamento = '2018-01-22 00:00:00'
       group by negociacao_parcela.data_pagamento, negociacao_parcela.id_agrupador
     ) as negociacao_parcela
where negociacao_parcela_item.id_agrupador = negociacao_parcela.id_agrupador
  and negociacao_parcela.data_pagamento = '2018-01-22 00:00:00';
```

e pra resolver o problema de vez, vc precisa de outro campo (nao sei se vc jah tem) para agrupar as parcelas e os itens da parcela de uma negociacao. Assim vc pode fazer o join.

Nao testei na minha maquina, entao talvez falte alguma virgula, 'as' ou algo similar.